# HTML form renders slashes before quotes in text area box

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know what could be wrong with my code? When a user inputs text into the text area box, quotes are rendered with back slashes before them, single quotes behave the same way. I have tried several combinations of code but nothing has worked. Could someone help me out? Thanks.

Here is my code: ------->

```
/* Email Variables */
$emailSubject = 'You have received an inquiry from your website';
$webMaster = 'info@3elementsreview.com';

/* Data Variables */
$first = $_POST['First'];
$last = $_POST['Last'];
$email = $_POST['E-Mail'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];



$body = <<<EOD
<span style="color:#454545; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.6em;">$first</span><br>

<span style="color:#454545; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.6em;">$last</span><br>

<span style="color:#454545; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.6em;">$email</span><br>
<br>
<span style="color:#252525; font-size:1.4em;">$message</span><br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);
```

Comment: You could probably use `$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));` etc. and do the same for the other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using PHP's [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function:

Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (`\'` becomes `'` and so on.)

Double backslashes (`\\`) are made into a single backslash (`\`).

```
$first = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['First']));
$last = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Last']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['E-Mail']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in your `php.ini` or call `strip_slashes()` on your data prior using it.

Also you will also soon be attracting spammers as your script can be easily used to mass mailing as it's hackable so anyone can inject own headers (incl. CC: or BCC: to your mail). See this (quickly googled) article on header injection: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228389-preventing-php-mail-header-injections/

Comment: Ill be attracting spammers based on my code regardless, or if I strip out the slashes?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
var_dump(preg_replace("@[/\\\]@", "", $variable));
```